# Python - Reshaping Grouped DataFrame Data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a grouped dataframe that needs to be reshaped using `to_time_series_dataset` function from `tslearn`.

A set of time series should be formatted as a three-dimensional array with shape `(num_series, max_length, 1)`, which the `tslearn.utils` function mentioned does just that. However the user needs to include every array in it.

```
from tslearn.utils import to_time_series_dataset
my_first_time_series = [1, 3, 4, 2]
my_second_time_series = [1, 2, 4, 2]
formatted_dataset = to_time_series_dataset([my_first_time_series, my_second_time_series])
print(formatted_dataset.shape)
(2, 4, 1)
```

How do I use this `to_time_series_dataset` function with this dataframe below if I have 99 individual columns?

```
import pandas as pd
import tslearn
from tslearn.utils import to_time_series_dataset

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID1': [1,2,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,0],
    'ID2': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],
    'ID99': [1,1,1,4,4,6,7,9,9,9]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
formatted_dataset = to_time_series_dataset(df.values)
print(formatted_dataset)
```